# iOS - Allocating custom UITableViewCell throwing NSMallocException

Tags: ios, uitableview, malloc, swift

I'm working on an iOS app in Swift, which I know is currently in beta, but so far I've been able to work around all the little issues until I came across this one. I have a table view which is going to be populated by custom table cells of the class `FavoriteRowCell`. Here is the class (which I've simplified in hopes of solving it through process of elimination):

```swift
class FavoriteRowCell
:UITableViewCell {

    var data:ImageInfo?;

    init() {
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "favoritesIdentifier");
    }

    func setData(data:ImageInfo) {
        self.data = data;
    }
}
```

And here is my cell recycling logic in my UITableViewDataSource implementation:

```swift
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:FavoriteRowCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("favoritesIdentifier") as? FavoriteRowCell;

    if(!cell) {
        cell = FavoriteRowCell();
    }

    var data:ImageInfo = favorites[indexPath!.row];
    cell!.setData(data);

    return cell!;
}
```

When I run this in the simulator, everything works perfectly. However, when I run it on my test iPod Touch, I get an NSMallocException and the app crashes. It happens when it tries to create the `FavoriteRowCell` object, but I can't figure out why.

Has anybody come across something similar, or is there anything you can see that I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: I am not. Empty iOS project with programatically-created UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your cell with:

```
cell = FavoriteRowCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "favoritesIdentifier")
```

Comment: I modified my constructor so that I could create it like this. Unfortunately no change.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the cause of the issue. The `ImageInfo` type is a struct, not a class, so I guess that was causing the problem.